# Core.NET Select List doesn't reset on Postback when bound item reset

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a SELECT list on a .NET Core razor page that never seems to reset:-

HTML:

```
    <form asp-page="./TestDropdown" method="post">
        <div class="col-12">
            <strong>Gender in memory: @Model.Gender</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <select asp-for="@Model.Gender" asp-items="@Model.GenderList" class="form-control">
                      <option value="">Gender</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <input asp-page-handler="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default btn-block" />
                <input asp-page-handler="ClearSearch" type="submit" value="Clear Search" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

C#:

```cs
    public class TestDropdownModel : PageModel
    {
        public TestDropdownModel()
        {
            InitSearchList();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public SelectList GenderList { get; set; }

        public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostClearSearch()
        {
            Gender = "";
            InitSearchList();
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostSearch()
        {
            InitSearchList();
            return Page();
        }

        private void InitSearchList()
        {
            GenderList = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Male", "Female" })
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
```

***Expected Behavior***

1. On GET no gender is selected
2. When Male is selected from the SELECT list and SEARCH clicked the page reloads
3. The Page reloads Male is selected in the list.
4. Gender label displayed as Male
5. Click Clear Search `OnPostClearSearch()` is executed, Gender set to ""
6. Page method with Male and Female options nothing selected
7. Gender in Memory Label is Blank

***Actual Behavior***

1. On GET no gender is selected
2. When Male is selected from the SELECT list and SEARCH clicked the page reloads
3. The Page reloads Male is selected in the list.
4. Gender label displayed as Male
5. Click Clear Search `OnPostClearSearch()` is executed, `Gender` set to ""
6. Page reloads with Male and Female options **"Male" selected** even though was set to "" in 6 ?? `<option selected="selected">Male</option>`
7. Gender Label is empty

Comment: Is it actually "selected" (i.e. `<option selected="selected">` appears in the rendered page source) or is it just the default (i.e. first) item in the `<select>`? Have you looked at the raw HTTP requests to see what's going on?

Comment: Did you try setting the IsSelected value for the selectlist item to false?

Comment: `<option selected="selected">Male</option>` rendered in source

Comment: @imAbhi how would I do that that the parameter is either present `<option selected="selected">option</option>` (selected) or not present `<option >option</option>` (not selected) there is no `selected="false"`as this equates to true I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is being repopulated from ModelState. Add `ModelState.Clear();` to your `OnPostClearSearch` method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostClearSearch()
{
    Gender = "";
    ModelState.Clear();
    InitSearchList();
    return Page();
}
```